# Asking opinion about table structure

Tags: mysql, database, table-structure

I'm working on a project to make a digital form of this paper
[this paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OorHR.png)  (can't post image)
and the data will displayed on a Web in a simple table view. There will be NO altering, deleting, updating. It's just displaying (via SELECT * of course) the data inputted.
The data will be inserted via android app and stored in a single table which has 30 columns in mysql.
and the question is, is it a good idea if i use a single table? because i think there will be no complex operation in the sql.
and the other question is, am i violating some rules for this method?
I need your opinion. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally ok to use only one table, if that suits your needs. What you can do to make the database a little bit 'smarter' is add new tables for attributes in your paper that will be repeated. So, for example, the Soil Type could be another table where there are two columns, ID and Description, and you will use it as a foreign key in each record in the main table. You need this if you want your database to be in [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

To sum up, yes you can have one table if that's all you need. However, adding more tables might help save some space and make your database more flexible. It's up to you to decide! :)

Comment: nice idea there.
i can't vote you up because of reputation but, thanks a lot !